Postfix-Dovecot LMTP delay setting
I noticed something like 20s delay between Postfix and Dovecot LMTP. I use socket at private/dovecot-lmtp to connect between the two.
Everything runs fine, and I don't mind about some delay to deliver a batch, but I think 20s is too long. Is the delay from postfix, or dovecot? And is there any way I can adjust this?
Thank you.


I do not see the delay you are seeing. Show configuration and logs.

From the log, connect at 14:10:55, the email delivered at 14:11:15. Connection at 14:21:11, the email delivered at 14:21:31. Connection at 14:26:25, the email delivered at 14:26:45. Will post the config at Monday. It's Saturday, and I can't access lab server at office today. But I didn't touch any configuration yet, other than dovecot-lmtp and postfix to lmtp.
